# How to implement a numerical formula across the items in a netlogo list

Tags: list, netlogo

I have to do some operations in netlogo using `Lists`. While i can do simple tasks with them i am not yet proficient enough to code my current requirements.

I have a scenario where turtles have variables called `Current-Age` and `Previous-Age`. And turtles can be born and die if they don't meet a certain `threshold`.

I want to implement the following formula for each patch.

```
Best-list = (-1/Previous-Age) * (Distance between Patch & Turtle) for all the turtles

Best = Min [ Best-list]
```

I know the steps involved but have been unsuccessful in coding them. Following are the steps:

1. Create a list with all the current turtles that are alive
2. Create a second list which contains the Previous-Age
3. Create a third list with the distance between an individual patch and each of the live turtles
4. Then create another list with the output from the the `Best-List` formula for all the turtles in the list
5. Finally find the `Min` value in the list and store the name/who# of turtle with the minimum value in a separate variable called `Best-Turtle`

This is the code that i tried but didn't work.

```
set turtle-list (list turtles)
set turtle-age-list n-values length(turtle-list) [0]
set turtle-patch-dist-list n-values length(turtle-list) [0]
set best-list n-values length(turtle-list) [0]

ask patches[
foreach turtle-list(
set turtle-age-list replace-item ?1 turtle-age-list Previous-Age of turtles with [turtle= ?1]
)
]
```

I couldn't proceed to the next steps since the above code itself was not correct.

Would appreciate help with the code, thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lists are probably not the simplest way to do this. However, if you must use lists for some reason, I think what you're asking for is possible. I'm not exactly sure what you mean with best- are you trying to have each patch assess which turtle is the best turtle for that patch, and store that variable in a global list? I'm going to assume that's what you mean, but if I'm misunderstanding I think you can adapt what I do here to what you need.

First, any list passed to `foreach` must be the same length. So, since you mean to do this per-patch, make sure that every patch calls the procedure of list creation, not just for checking the lists. Next, review the dictionary for `n-values`- the syntax for the reporter means you need to use the reporter you're trying to receive- using `n-values length(turtle-list) [0]` will just give you a list of zeroes that is the same length as the number of turtles.

So each patch needs to create these lists- make sure you either define the `patches-own` for the list variables, or just use `let` to define the lists inside the procedure. You would need a list of ordered turtles, their previous ages, and the distance from the patch calling the procedure to each turtle. Next, you can create a list that generates a value according to your formula. Then, you can use the `position` primitive to find the location of the minimum value in your formula-generated list and use that to index the turtle *with* that value.

It might look something like

```
to numerical

  set best-turtle []

  ask patches [
    let turtle-list (sort turtles)  ;;; list of sorted turtles
    let turtle-prev-age-list n-values length(turtle-list) [ [i] -> [pre_age] of turtle i ] ;;; list of previous ages of turtles, in same order as above
    let turtle-patch-dist n-values length(turtle-list) [ [i] -> distance turtle i ] ;;; list of distance from this patch to each turtle, in same order
    set best-list n-values length(turtle-list) [ [i] -> ( ( -1 / ( item i turtle-prev-age-list ) ) * ( item i turtle-patch-dist ) ) ]  ;;; list of calculated values for each turtle
    let best-position position (min best-list) best-list  ;;; gets the index of minimum value
    set best-turtle lput item best-position turtle-list best-turtle ;;; adds the best turtle for this patch to the global list of best turtles
  ]

end
```

The above procedure assumes that your turtles have a `pre_age` variable, patches have a `best-list` variable, and the list of each patches 'best turtle' is held in the global variable `best-turtle`. From there, you can use `foreach` to ask turtles in the list to do something. Note that if a turtle's previous age is 0, you will get a divide by zero error.

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
turtles-own [age previous-age]

to-report evalfrom [_patch]
  report  (- distance _patch) / previous-age
end

to test
  ca
  crt 25 [
    set age (10 + random 75)
    set previous-age age - random 10
  ]
  print min-one-of turtles [evalfrom (patch 0 0)]
end
```